# Pulling teeth vs Pulling nails

Tags: idioms, phrases

So, my friend said "getting a compliment out of X is like pulling teeth". Somehow I always remembered that expression as "pulling nails with a plier". He pointed that the expression doesn't exists. So I was wondering where I heard that phrase. I am Indian, so is it British English? Or does the phrase not exists at all?

Comment: But *pulling nails with pliers* sounds easy, and the point is that *pulling teeth* is difficult and painful.  But then, I am a US English speaker, so maybe it's just that I'm not used to the other idiom!

Comment: I mean, I am sure it would hurt a hell of a lot to have one's nails pulled with a pliers lol

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the kind of nails that you drive into wood with a hammer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The established expression is ***[like pulling teeth:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/like-pulling-teeth)***
​

> If you say that making someone do something was like pulling teeth, you mean it was very difficult and they did not want to do it:
>
> - Getting her to tell me about her childhood was like pulling teeth.

Maybe the nail  version  is a variant, but not a common one as far as I can see.

Comment: One difference is that "pulling (finger) nails" is a torture, intended to be painful, whereas "pulling teeth" is a necessary process and although painful, can be done as gently and kindly as possible, especially as the analogy is about getting someone to talk about the past.

Comment: +1 The only *idiom* is *like pulling teeth*. *Like pulling nails* is not an idiom at all.